# How can I create narrow band noise in C#?

Tags: c#, audio, filtering, signal-processing, naudio

My problem is very spesific. I want to create narrow band noise for my small wpf application. I am using NAudio library for creating a infinite stream of noise that can be stopped and started by user. I created Tone(Simple sinus wave), Warble(Sinus wave that is modulated by another wave) and White noise.

This is the class I use in order to make any ISampleProvider that is stereo be able to give sound to left, right or both depending what user wants.

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;

namespace AppForSoundCard
{
    public class SignalStereoProvider : ISampleProvider
    {
        private readonly ISampleProvider sample;
        public WaveFormat WaveFormat => sample.WaveFormat;
        public float LeftVolume { get; set; }
        public float RightVolume { get; set; }

        public SignalStereoProvider(ISampleProvider sample)
        {
            if (sample.WaveFormat.Channels != 2)
                throw new ArgumentException("Source sample provider must be stereo");
            this.sample = sample;
        }

        public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            int samplesRead = sample.Read(buffer, offset, count);

            for (int n = 0; n < count; n += 2)
            {
                buffer[offset + n] *= LeftVolume;
                buffer[offset + n + 1] *= RightVolume;
            }

            return samplesRead;
        }
    }
}
```

I use this code to generate audio stream that I mentioned. You will ask what is NarrowBand32 is. It is the class that supposed to generate narrowband noise from white noise. I will write it's code after next paragraph.

```
signalGenerator = new SignalGenerator();
signalGenerator.Type = SignalGeneratorType.White;
signalGenerator.Gain = 1.0;
signalGenerator.Frequency = Frequency;
narrowBand = new NarrowBandProvider32(signalGenerator, Frequency, 96000, 100, dB);
stereoProvider = new SignalStereoProvider(narrowBand)
{
    RightVolume = !((ComboBoxItem)RoutingCombobox.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString().Equals("Left") ? (float)Math.Pow(10, (dB - 80) / 20.0) * (float)Settings.Default["ReferenceAmplitudeFor" + Frequency.ToString()] : 0.0f,
    LeftVolume = !((ComboBoxItem)RoutingCombobox.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString().Equals("Right") ? (float)Math.Pow(10, (dB - 80) / 20.0) * (float)Settings.Default["ReferenceAmplitudeFor" + Frequency.ToString()] : 0.0f
};
Output.Init(stereoProvider);
```

I first generate an white noise using NAudio's SignalGenerator class. Then give it to the NarrowbandProvider32 that I wrote. Which suppose to make white noise narrowband. After all that I make the sound either go left or right or both.
Left and right volume is amplitute value for desibel value that is given by user. There is a combobox about routng in which you can choose, left, right, bilateral. Depending on your choise leftvolume is the apmlitute, right volume is the amplitute or both of them is amplitute.

I have visited several sites about how a narrowband noise can be generated. They were all suggesting bandpass filtering a white noise to generate narrow band noise. I tried that. It sort of did what I wanted but it was narrower than I wanted. You can find frequency response of the noise that [I generated for 500 hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jgFB.jpg).

Here is the NarrowBand32 class code for that noise

```
using NAudio.Dsp;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;

namespace AppForSoundCard
{
    class NarrowBandProvider32 : ISampleProvider
    {
        ISampleProvider sample;
        float lowFreq;
        float highFreq;
        BiQuadFilter biQuad;
        public WaveFormat WaveFormat => sample.WaveFormat;

        public NarrowBandProvider32(ISampleProvider sample, float frequency, float sampleRate, float q, float dB)
        {
            if (sample.WaveFormat.Channels != 2)
                throw new ArgumentException("Source sample provider must be stereo");

            this.sample = sample;
            //Low and High frequency variables are defined like this in audiometry.
            //these variables are the boundaries for narrowband noise
            lowFreq = (float)Math.Round(frequency / Math.Pow(2, 1.0 / 4.0)); 
            highFreq = (float)Math.Round(frequency * Math.Pow(2, 1.0 / 4.0));
            biQuad = BiQuadFilter.BandPassFilterConstantSkirtGain(sampleRate, frequency, q);
            biQuad.SetHighPassFilter(sampleRate, lowFreq, q);
            biQuad.SetLowPassFilter(sampleRate, highFreq, q);
        }

        public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            int samplesRead = sample.Read(buffer, offset, count);


            for (int i = 0; i < samplesRead; i++)
                buffer[offset + i] = biQuad.Transform(buffer[offset + i]);

            return samplesRead;
        }
    }
}
```

Those the arguments I gave:
`narrowBand = new NarrowBandProvider32(signalGenerator, Frequency, 96000, 100, dB);`

As I said this noise is close to the narrowband noise that is defined in audiometry but it is more narrow. Narrowband noise for 500 hz in audiometry [has this frequency response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvEfm.jpg).

As you can see it is more wide than the noise that I generated. How can I genereate a narrowband noise that is close to narrowband noise in audiometry for any hz. I only gave examples of 500 hz for the images but in my code you can generate a noise between 150hz to 8000hz. What filter should I use to filter white noise in order to generate [that type of narrowband noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvEfm.jpg). Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
I find a standart which explains how a narrowband noise should be for any frequency and desibel.

> Where narrow-band masking is required, the noise band shall be centred geometrically
> around the test frequency. The band limits for the masking noise are given in [Table 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjsR9.png).
> Outside these band limits the sound pressure spectrum density level of the noise shall fall at
> a rate of at least 12 dB per octave for at least three octaves and outside these three octaves it
> shall be at least 36 dB below the level at the centre frequency. Measurements are required in
> the range from 31,5 kHz to 10 kHz for instruments limited to 8 kHz. For EHF instruments
> measurements are required up to 20 kHz.
> Due to limitations of transducers, ear simulators, acoustic couplers and mechanical couplers,
> measurements of the bandwidth at 4 kHz and above may not accurately describe the
> spectrum of the masking noise. Therefore at centre frequencies above 3,15 kHz
> measurements shall be made electrically across the transducer terminals.

With that definition, I guess just an standart bandpass filter wouldn't work and I have to define a custom filter for the noise. Is there a C# library that allows defining custom filters. If there is how should I define the custom filter in order to make noises in that standart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They were all suggesting bandpass filtering a white noise to generate narrow band noise. I tried that. It sort of did what I wanted but it was narrower than I wanted.

The approach of applying a bandpass filter to a white noise source makes sense. The problem is just that the bandpass filter design is too narrow. You can make it wider by reducing the `q`, moving the `lowFreq` and `highFreq` a bit outward, or switching to a different filter design method.

I suggest that rather than coding directly in C#, it might be useful to prototype this first in Python using the [scipy.signal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) library, which has a various tools for designing and working with filters.

In the code below, I vary the `c` parameter to tweak the low and high edges of the band.

**Code:**

```
# Copyright 2022 Google LLC.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig

fs = 96000  # Sample rate.
f0 = 500  # Center frequency in Hz.

# Generate noise with a few different bandwidths.
for c in [1.03, 1.07, 1.15]:
  # Design a second-order Butterworth filter bandpass filter.
  sos = sig.butter(2, [f0 / c, f0 * c], 'bandpass', output='sos', fs=fs)
  # Generate white noise.
  white_noise = np.random.randn(fs)
  # Run it through the filter.
  output = sig.sosfilt(sos, white_noise)
  # Use Welch's method to estimate the PSD of the filtered noise.
  f, psd = sig.welch(output, fs, nperseg=4096)

  plt.semilogx(f, 10 * np.log10(psd), label=f'c = {c}')

plt.axvline(x=f0, color='k')
plt.xlim(50, fs/2)
plt.ylim(-140, -40)
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('PSD (dB)', fontsize=15)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: I tried PeakingEQ filter with Highpass and Lowpass filters, with some adjusting and min maxing, it worked greatly. Thanks for the effort. Thank you for answering my question.